# Angular 1.x testing are good for angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, protractor, karma-runner

I'm starting a new app that is made with angular 1.x, and I'm thinking about changing to angular 2. Do you recommend me to do that?

A part of that question, the most important one is that I want to know if Angular testing using Karma and Protractor are good for Angular 2. If I switch to Angular 2, can I run the tests to verify if the functionality still being the same?

I don't have the tests yet, so if I have to do it in a special way in order to be able to do that is welcome too.

Comment: *Do you recommend me to do that?*: that is opinion-based. But the current version is ANgular 4.x, so no, I wouldn't recomment using Angular 2. You of course won't be able to use the existing karma unit tests, testing your existing AngularJS components, to test your Angular 2 components. Your protractor e2e tests could be reused, if they don't rely on NG1 specific selectors.

Comment: If you are starting from scratch start with the latest angular 2 / 4 and use angular-cli. There is not big difference between angular 2 and 4. Karma is used for unit testing too but you will have to write new tests as @JBNizet said. existing e2e protractor tests should work in new project.

Comment: I'm not starting from scratch, I have some controllers and services done, and I want to switch to angular 2. The tests are going to be completely different or I just have to adapt them?